# How to use a UIView subclass from a framework within interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, interface-builder

### Problem

I have started to separate my code into modules, so I made a framework called `GEView`.

The problem is in interface builder. The `UIView` is subclassed using the framework:

[image: Custom class]

However, I can't see any `@IBInspectable` properties. It did work when this class was in the project instead of separated into a framework. How do I see these so I can change the properties?

### Framework class

```
/// UIView subclass to allow creating corners, shadows, and borders in storyboards.
@IBDesignable
open class GEView: UIView {

    /* ... */


    // MARK: - Rounded corners
    @IBInspectable
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }


    /* ... */
}
```

### Framework implementation

[image: Frameworks]

I even added `import GEView` in the class for this view controller in the interface builder that contains this view, which still doesn't work.

It's my first time using my own framework in a project so I could have created or imported it incorrectly. Here is the project hierarchy:

[image: App hierarchy]

### Half-working method

I managed to get the `Interface Builder` to at least recognize the `GEView` class. I tried this code in my project:

```
@IBDesignable
class IBGEView: GEView {

    @IBInspectable
    var _cornerRadius: CGFloat { return cornerRadius }
}
```

Then I would subclass in `Interface Builder` with `IBGEView`. By no means is this a solution I was looking for, so I am still looking. **This is not a solution.**

Comment: As of now - I am no longer using it in a framework until there is an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the module as well. Generally, it is the name of the framework. Uncheck module from target and write the name of the framework there

Comment: Still doesn't work - also, `GEView` was not an option in the drop down anyway

Comment: If you are importing GEView in your class and it is compiling then definitely you have a GEView named module. Sometimes xcode does not recognize it. Pretty sure that you have to mention the correct module name there.

Comment: It's my first time using frameworks, so I may have done something wrong when implementing them

Comment: Still no luck though